# HTML+CSS tooltip: Weird behavior in table with rowspan

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have created a html table which contains tooltips for each cell. I don't understand at this point, why most of the tooltips are drawn above the table while some of the tooltips are covered by neighbouring cells? I just played around with the z-index, but could get it working properly. 
Do you you have any ideas?

Since I am not allowed to post images, here is only a link:

[Comparing image of working and non working tooltip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7763161/Clipboard01.jpg)

Please don't take the css stuff too serious, I am no web developer, I just wanted a quick html table solution.

So the example can be found right here:
https://jsfiddle.net/6foqnLkm/

The related tooltip css code (found on the web)

```
/* Hide the tooltip content by default */
[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-transition: ease 0.5s all;
  -o-transition: ease 0.5s all;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.5s all;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

/* Position tooltip above the element */
[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 110%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

/* Triangle hack to make tooltip look like a speech bubble */
[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 110%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

/* Show tooltip content on hover */
[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  bottom: 90%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
[data-tooltip]:before {z-index:9;}
```

[Click here for Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ttpgk9vf/3/)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Remove "z-index : 2" in [data-tooltip] and add "z-index: 9" in [data-tooltip]:before

```
[data-tooltip] {
   position: relative;
   cursor: pointer;
}

[data-tooltip]:before {
   z-index:9;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 110%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   margin-left: -80px;
   padding: 7px;
   width: 160px;
   -moz-border-radius: 6px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
   border-radius: 6px;
   background-color: black;
   color: #fff;
   content: attr(data-tooltip);
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1.2;
}
```